# Jest "No tests found, exiting with code 1" error on Windows 10 in React Redux application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am attempting to run Jest on my project. I am on a Windows 10. I only have one test in one test file.

In `package.json`:

```
    "test": "jest"
```

My directory structure:

```
    src/
        app/
            routeName/
                redux/
                    action.tests.js
```

My output:

```
No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
In C:\Users\myUsername\Documents\myApp
  47 files checked.
  testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x), **/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x) - 0 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: \\node_modules\\ - 47 matches
  testRegex:  - 0 matches
Pattern:  - 0 matches
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

According to the documentation [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testregex-string-array-string), Jest should look for anything that has `test.js` in the name.

I have also tried `tests.js` and that didn't work either.

I created a folder in the root of the project and put a test in there as `__tests__/tests.js` and that did work, but I do not want it placed there.

I have seen several tickets and questions about questions that are superficially similar, but all of those involve more complex configurations, or bugs that were supposedly patched already. I have no special configurations set. The documentation says this should work. Tutorials I have read for Jest include the exact setup I am currently using.

I am using Babel and Webpack. I installed the `jest` and `babel-jest` packages. I also added jest to the ESLint environment.

[edit] updated to properly document my problem, which I answered below. I lost track of my file naming.

Comment: I was getting the same error when running the test from IntelliJ. In my case, the run configuration was not set properly. I had to correctly define the 'Jest package' field in the configuration with '~you-project/node_modules/jest'. There was 'node_modules/react-scripts' originally. I stumbled over this topic here while searching for my solution, so maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I am a bloody idiot and I didn't pay attention to the details.

Jest is looking for `test.js` specifically. Not `testS.js`. My files were labeled as `tests.js`. It worked inside `__tests__/` because Jest just looks for anything inside there.

I got it working just fine now, and it shall remain up as a testament to me not looking at the specifics of the regex matches.

Comment: In my case, I had forgotten to locate the test in a `__tests__/` directory.

Comment: Oh the hours of my life that have gone to off-by-one errors with s characters...

Answer (score 21):

I had the same Problem with a React-App. Make sure, that the jest config file has the correct file pattern to find the tests:

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
    testMatch: [
        '<rootDir>/src/**/*.test.js',
        '<rootDir>/src/**/*.test.jsx',
    ],
    ...
}
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative scenario, assuming you don't have tests in your project,

To turn this behavior off, you can add a `--passWithNoTests` flag in the scripts of your package.json file, i.e.:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "react-scripts test --passWithNoTests"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> No tests found, exiting with code 1
> ```

All I had to do was `npm install`.

Then I hit the Debug link at the top of my test. The test was found and execution stopped at the breakpoint. A simple solution to a very frustrating problem.

Answer (score 1):

From my side, I was getting this error because I had placed myself (cd) in the directory where the chromeDriver was installed, so as not to have to add its path to $Path. After I added chromeDriver to $Path, and placed myself in the directory of my project, everything went fine.

Comment: What is the path of `chromeDriver`?

Comment: Leopold can you please share what you entered into your PATH ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I wanted to run my tests inside `drone` CI pipeline and had the same error what solved my problem was simply adding `workspace` to my project.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the name of the file. For example
if you have a **customer.js** or **customer.ts** file and you want to test it. Create a new file name is **customer.test.js**  or
**customer.test.ts** after npm test it will test the file which just for testing .

Answer (score 0):

check if it is small case like filename.test.js.
I made a mistake ComponentName.Test.js and got error, fixed it by ComponetName.test.js

Answer (score 0):

I have --passWithNoTests in my package.json file. Still facing the issues. because of my test case file named without test.
Try checking your test file name once.

Answer (score 0):

1/ Modify your package.json
add --testMatch **/tests/**/*.test.js in package.json file.
Example:

```
scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
    "test": "cross-env JEST_TEST=false jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "test:ci": "npm run test -- --testResultsProcessor=\"jest-junit\" --watchAll=false --ci --coverage --testMatch **/tests/**/*.test.js cross-env JEST_TEST=false"
  },
...
```

2/ Execute

```
run: npm run test:ci
```